# mPDF in CodeIgniter page orientation won't do landscape

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

I'm using mPDF in CodeIgniter.

here is my lib (pdf.php)

```
class pdf {
    function pdf()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
    }

    function load($param=NULL)
    {
        include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';
        if ($params == NULL)
        {
            $param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3,"L"';
        }
        return new mPDF($param);
    }
}
```

this is my controller

```
$filename = 'qwerty';
//...
// As PDF creation takes a bit of memory, we're saving the created file in /downloads/reports/
$pdfFilePath = FCPATH."reports\\"   . $filename . ".pdf";
//$data['page_title'] = 'Hello world'; // pass data to the view
for($i=0;$i>=0;$i++)
{
    if(file_exists($pdfFilePath) == TRUE)
    {
        $pdfFilePath = FCPATH."reports\\"   . $filename . $i . ".pdf";
    } else {
        break 1;
    }
}
ini_set('memory_limit','32M');
$html = $this->load->view('certificate/certificate', $isi,TRUE); // render the view into HTML
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load($param);
\$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'|{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822));
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F'); // save to file because we can
```

even with that config (`$param`), the result still give me portrait file, thus, CSS inside is pretty messed up.

What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My name is Rhonald Brito, it is my first time here, I have about 1 year using Codeigniter and MPDF, here I let you know my code:

```
public function Make_PDF($view, $data, $file_name) {
    $html = $this->load->view($view, $data, true);
    $this->mpdf = new mPDF();
    $this->stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
    $this->mpdf->AddPage('L', // L - landscape, P - portrait
            '', '', '', '',
            30, // margin_left
            30, // margin right
            30, // margin top
            30, // margin bottom
            18, // margin header
            12); // margin footer
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //$this->mpdf->Output($file_name, 'D'); // download force
    $this->mpdf->Output($file_name, 'I'); // view in the explorer

    // for more information rhonalejandro@gmail.com
}
```

Comment: you're right, I was solving this by adding `AddPage` to create one landscaped page, instead of declaring on the object creation (`new`).. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Set format to 'A4-L' in constructor.

Comment: This is more like a comment (like the comment of Alberto in one of the other answers). It's better to give a full answer, and / or earn some reputation so that you will be able to use comments.

Answer (score 3):

When creating your new PDF use the following to set it to landscape

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'L');
```

Hope this helps

More information [here](http://www.smaizys.com/php/mpdf-html-to-pdf-introduction/)

Comment: When using A4 format, correct way to get landscape mode is to switch it to ‘A4-L’.

Answer (score 1):

i use the same code as yours, and i add Rhonald Brito's code on mine. it works well

```
 $pdf->AddPage('L', // L - landscape, P - portrait
        '', '', '', '',
        30, // margin_left
        30, // margin right
        30, // margin top
        30, // margin bottom
        18, // margin header
        12); // margin footer
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Using mPDF with CodeIgniter](https://davidsimpson.me/2013/05/19/using-mpdf-with-codeigniter/) to see where to pass my parameters and applying Pooshonk's suggested parameters, I got the desired effect of setting all pages to Landscape mode with a syntax that suited mPDF in the helper of my Codeigniter project.

```
$CI = get_instance();
$CI->load->library('pdf');
$html = $CI->load->view($templatePath, $dataArray, true);
$pdf = $CI->pdf->load('utf-8', 'L');
```

---

p.s. After a bit more experimentation with mPDF6.0 in my CI project, I discovered that passing `true` has the same effect.  I assume it allows mPDF to determine automagically the more appropriate orientation for the supplied data.  If this is true, it is more flexible, but probably also requires a bit more processing (when I *know* that I always want landscape orientation for this specific template).

```
$pdf = $CI->pdf->load(true);
```