# How to set the page in landscape mode in mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using `mpdf` library in PHP to create a pdf file from HTML. I need to set the page mode in `landscape` mode.

Here is the code I am using :

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

However, this is setting the page mode in `portrait` mode. Any idea, how to set the landscape mode in mpdf ?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946537/mpdf-in-codeigniter-page-orientation-wont-do-landscape

Answer (score 35):

You can do that by adding -L to your page format. So in our case you'd add another param to your constructor:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4-L');
```

More about mPDF constructor params can be found <s>[here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184)</s>(deadlink).

Answer (score 10):

In mPDF **version 7.0.0** or later the configuration need to be parsed as *array[]*:

```
$myMpdf = new Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => 'A4-L',
    'orientation' => 'L'
]
```

---

In older version **before** version 7.0.0. it need to be done like this:

```
myMpdf = new mPDF(
    '',    // mode - default ''
    'A4-L',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
    0,     // font size - default 0
    '',    // default font family
    15,    // margin_left
    15,    // margin right
    16,    // margin top
    16,    // margin bottom
    9,     // margin header
    9,     // margin footer
    'L'    // L - landscape, P - portrait
);
```

Answer (score 9):

This may be useful for you.

The last Parameter is orientation.

```
class mPDF ([ string $mode [, mixed $format [, float $default_font_size [, string $default_font [, float $margin_left , float $margin_right , float $margin_top , float $margin_bottom , float $margin_header , float $margin_footer [, string $orientation ]]]]]])
```

**P: DEFAULT Portrait**

**L: Landscape**

**"-L" to force a Landscape page orientation**

```
// Define a Landscape page size/format by name
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');

// Define a page using all default values except "L" for Landscape orientation
$mpdf=new mPDF('','', 0, '', 15, 15, 16, 16, 9, 9, 'L');
```

You can dig more into it <s>[here](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/mpdf.html)</s> [here](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-size-orientation.html)

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 8):

Check the docs for the [mPDF constructor](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184&searchstring=landscape).

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c', 'A4-L');
```

Comment: whenever I use the `'c'`, the custom font I'm using doesn't show, instead the font in the pdf file is just an ordinary font (Times New Roman, I guess).  why is this?

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 6):

add options like this:

```
 $mpdf = new mPDF('',    // mode - default ''
 '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
 0,     // font size - default 0
 '',    // default font family
 15,    // margin_left
 15,    // margin right
 16,     // margin top
 16,    // margin bottom
 9,     // margin header
 9,     // margin footer
 'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to change the orientation is to pass an array with arguments.

This variable gets passed to the constructor and is called `$config`

`public function __construct(array $config = []){
}`

Down below are the default configurations of the Mpdf

```
$default_config= [
                'mode' => '',
                'format' => 'A4',
                'default_font_size' => 0,
                'default_font' => '',
                'margin_left' => 15,
                'margin_right' => 15,
                'margin_top' => 16,
                'margin_bottom' => 16,
                'margin_header' => 9,
                'margin_footer' => 9,
                'orientation' => 'P',
            ];
```

To change the orientation from Portrait to Landscape just change the "orientation" parameter as it is written below.

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['orientation' => 'L']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi go for here to find that. [AddPage() have the parameter to set that....](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=29)

```
$mpdf->AddPage('L',.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

In mPDF version 7.2.1 works form me :

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(array('', '', 0, '', 15, 15, 16, 16, 9, 9, 'L'));

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>This is just a <strong>test</strong>, This is just a <strong>test</strong></p>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `October 2022`, as documented in Mpdf github page, it suffices to add `mode` and `format` array parameters, or simply `orientation`.

```
// Define a default Landscape page size/format by name
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L']);

// Define a default page size/format by array - page will be 190mm wide x 236mm height
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => [190, 236]]);

// Define a default page using all default values except "L" for Landscape orientation
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['orientation' => 'L']);
```

[Go to the link](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-size-orientation.html)